# Linux Python NON-ASCII Character

Tags: python, linux

[image: Консоль]

Вот такая вот ошибка вот часть кода где он пишет ошибку

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import vk_api
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard,VkKeyboardColor
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
import time
import random
import mainFunctions
from threading import Thread

work = True
 vk=vk_api.VkApi(token="7554aee710f40a691c90a408c018f7c8434b7844a5ccd2b60cfe6338d9b21f1711b3d4448a6b469645513",scope=8192)
```

Comment: Используйте Python3

Comment: Если все-таки не хотите использовать Python3, то попробуйте вставить следующий код в начале модуля: `import sys` 
`reload(sys)` 
`sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')`. Напишите, пожалуйста, получилось ли устранить проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вы запускаете свой скрипт вот такой командой:

```
python file_name.py
```

Но скорее всего на самом деле вы хотите запустить свой скрипт через python 3. Но т.к. в линуксах второй питон установлен по умолчанию, команда python вызывает именно его. Поэтому используйте команду вот такого вида:

```
python3 file_name.py
```

Еще лучше, если Вы будете использовать виртуальное окружение для каждого своего проекта. Для этого сначала создайте его в директории с приложением:

```
python3 -m venv your_venv_name
```

Затем активируйте свое виртуальное окружение:

```
source your_venv_name/bin/activate
```

В виртуальном окружении у Вас не будет второго питона и третий будет вызываться командой python, поэтому можете запускать свой скрипт так:

```
python file_name.py
```